# Nightwatch with Chrome on Windows: Currently Unusable?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, nightwatch.js

Since my chrome update, I cannot make any nightwatch tests work on Windows 10.

At first the system simply couldn't set values.  So I updated to the latest nightwatch, then updated to latest chromedriver.exe and latest selenium jar.

Now the test simply shows data: in the url of the driven browser instead of loading the page.  There is also a "disable developer mode extensions" popup and a warning that "--ignore-certificate-errors" is no longer supported.

Any ideas what I'm supposed to have done?

- Chromedriver.exe version: 2.38
- Selenium Standalone Server: selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar
- Nightwatch version: nightwatch@0.9.21

Thanks for any help.  Here's my config:

```
{
  "src_folders": ["tests"],
  "output_folder": "reports",
  "custom_commands_path": "",
  "custom_assertions_path": "",
  "page_objects_path": "pages",
  "globals_path": "globals",

  "selenium": {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": "./lib/selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar",
    "log_path": "./reports",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4444,
    "cli_args": {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./lib/chromedriver.exe"
    }
  },
  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "launch_url": "https://modaquote.com",
      "selenium_port": 4444,
      "selenium_host": "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the _latest selenium jar_ for _nightwatch@0.9.21_  **selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update Chromedriver to match your new version of Chrome. It should fix there issues.

Comment: This was my problem.  I had reasonably up to date libraries, but it only worked once I had them using matching versions.  Sorry for the dumb question!